# Need to install Liberty 17 and JRE 7

Tags: java, websphere-liberty, ibm-installation-manager

I was attempting to use the Installation Manager install pack to setup 17.0.0.4 with JRE 7 (windows workstation). The install manager won't show Liberty 17 as an option even though my repo is setup correctly.  I can't install JRE 7 because it wants Liberty installed.  I tried using the IBM repos and it will only show Liberty 18 as well.  Any help appreciated.  Thanks!

Background - we support a vendor app that goes back to JRE 6 so we are unable to use Liberty 18.

Comment: Was able to use http://www.ibm.com/software/repositorymanager/com.ibm.websphere.liberty.BASE as the repo and show all versions.

Comment: If the application can only run on Java SE 6 I would strongly advocate talking to the app vendor to get something that will run on newer Java versions. Java SE 6 is out of standard support and security fix support ends at the end of the year.

Answer (score 1):

Select "show all versions" from the "Install Packages" dialogue.  Otherwise, IIM shows you only the latest package for each item.